# Is it possible to simulate a mouse click on a remote machine over SSH?

Tags: ssh

I have a python script which is SSH-ing into a remote machine to open a browser window and navigate to a specific page (this remote machine is connected to a display).

Is it possible to simulate a mouse click on this display so as to have some action performed on the web page?

If so how would I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try with, **PyAutoGUI**.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoGUI

It is a python library for controling both mouse & keyboard.

To not copy/paste the usage, check their official repo on the Github:

https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a number of tools that can simulate mouse or keyboard events, for example `xdotool`, `xte` or `xrecord/xmacro`.

No need to use Python.

However, your ssh-session must be authorized to connect to the display. This is usually something the owner of the display must allow you. See `man xhost` and `man xauth`, you often can find out where MIT authorization cookies with `ps axu | grep X`, looking at the commandline options of the X server.